# Probability from Expectation

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation

Having a little trouble understanding this notation from lecture. Hopefully someone can help clear it up, because I wasn't able to find this notation online. What exactly is I{A,w}?

```
Define: I{A, w} = 1 if w ∈ A and 0 if w ∈ 0.
Define: P(A) = E[ I{A,w} ] (expectation)
```

Prove: Given disjoint A, B, then P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B). Here's the proof from lecture:

```
I(A ∪ B, w) = I{A, w} + I{B, w} if A, B disjoint. Let's call this equation EQN.

Take 3 cases:
a) w ∉ A and w ∉ B: LHS of EQN = 0, RHS of EQN = 0
b) w ∈ A and w ∉ B: LHS of EQN = 1, RHS of EQN = 1
c) w ∉ A and w ∈ B: LHS of EQN = 1, RHS of EQN = 1

Take the expectation of both sides of EQN and use 
the fact that E(X_1 + E_2) = E(X_1) + E(X_2).
```

I think my confusion lies in what I{A, w} is. Would the solution look something like this?

```
E[I{A ∪ B, w}]  = E[I{A, w} + I{B, w}]
E[I{A ∪ B, w}]  = E[I{A, w}] + E[I{B, w}]
       P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B)
```

Also, if A ⊂ B, then I{A, w} ≤ I{B, w}. How would I go about proving this? Hopefully understanding the above will give me insight.

Thanks.

Comment: $I$ is an "indicator variable".  Very useful.  Just tells you if some property is or is not observed.  For example, if I throw balls randomly into urns I might want to consider $I_i$ , the indicator variable which tells me if the $i^{th}$ urn gets any balls or not.

Comment: $I(a,w)=0$ if $w$ is *not* in $A.$ You can look up "indicator function." [Last part of your quoted definition is misleading...]

Comment: BTW: I suppose you mean $\omega$ (lower case, last letter of Greek alphabet) instead of $w.$

Comment: Yeah, I mean omega, not w. Any thoughts on my two questions?

Answer (score 1):

$I$ is the indicator function, usually defined for a set A, parametrized with $w$

$$ I_A\{w\} = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } w \in A, \\
0 &\text{if } w \notin A.
\end{cases}
$$

Following your notation it's easy to prove that for disjoint sets 
$$I\{A ∪ B, w\}  = I\{A, w\} + I\{B, w\}$$

and the rest follows by taking expectations and linearity.